# add new packages to SDK manager

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm having a problem with SDK manager, for some reason I can't load new packages in SDK manager to download and I only can see installed packages.. is there any other way to add the packages? I need google play services package.. how can I add this package with another way?

Comment: Reinstall Adt Plugin

Answer (score 1):

You can user gradle and add the following dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}
```

Link for more info: [Info link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

Note: You need to use Android Studio IDE

Comment: I recommend Android Studio because he comes with the SDK integrated and other usefull features (I never wanted to install at first, but now I can say it is worth)

Answer (score 0):

ON your SDK manager Tools->Options and enable the following as shown in picture below
[image]

This should hopefully start downloading packages. There are other things that you could try like setting up the right proxy or reinstalling ADT.